# rm: cannot remove directory: `.'

Tags: bash

Executing this command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 '!' -name .scm -exec rm -rf {} + || true
```

is pretty fine if no file is available. otherwise this results in a message which looks like

```
rm: cannot remove directory: `.'
```

But the command work as expected. Do I have to bother about this message and how can I overcome this?

Best regards

Comment: You could also add `-mindepth 1`, to prevent `.` being included.

Comment: @Jameson great suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash you can simplify this using [extended globbing](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) (matches any file ending with `.scm`, including `.scm` itself):

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch .scm bar.txt
$ ls -a !(*.scm) # Change to `rm -rf`
bar.txt
```

Or you can follow [Jameson's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712775/rm-cannot-remove-directory/42715431#comment72546278_42712775) and use `-mindepth`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 '!' -name .scm -exec rm -rf {} + || true
```